# How to implement nested transactions in Java, Spring JDBC and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, transactions

In my application, I create trace records in the database whenever a service class function is called. Following is a pseudo code.

```
public Class A {
    Tracer tracer;
    B b;
    void functionA () {
        tracer.addTrace(input);
        TransactionManger.getTransaction(); // Transaction starts.
        result = b.functionB();
        if(result == 0) {
            // rollback
        } else {
            // commit
        }
    }
}

public Class B {
    Tracer tracer;
    int functionB () {
        tracer.addTrace(input);
        TransactionManger.getTransaction(); // Transaction starts.
        // Do whatever. Return.
    }
}
```

Assume `addTrace` function writes a record into database, in the above situation if `functionB` returns 0, the trace added into database is getting rolled back ? How to avoid this situation ? Looks like MySQL does not support nested transactions. So I cannot get a new transaction inside `addTrace` and close it there so the changes in `functionA` will not be committed before the result of `functionB` is computed.

Comment: Be prepared for the usual question: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Also, can you restate the problem please? It seems that you can first prepare a compound statement as a String and commit it once at the end of all checks.

Comment: Trace is different from actual transaction and they are different service classes. So I cannot make a compound statement out of them.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like addTrace() to execute in its own transaction, and commit as soon as it returns. That's what the REQUIRES_NEW transaction propagation is for. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-propagation-requires_new. You'd better use Spring as it's intended to be used: with declarative transaction handling.

Comment: Yes. That is what I want to do. Will try that and post the results.

Comment: @JBNizet, worked as expected. I would accept this for an answer if you post it.